# marshalling java object with AnyXmlType property loses information

Tags: java, jaxb

I am trying to marshal a java object that has a AnyXmlType property (the declaration of both classes are posted at the end).
The problem is when I try to marshal the java object to a ByteArrayOutputStream it loses the AnyXmlType information.
I am sure that I have the information in the class as I am printing it out before marshalling as follows

```
    Element any = decision.getDecisionMotivation().getAny();
    Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
    tidy.pprint(any, System.out);
```

then  I am marshalling

```
    final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    final JAXBContext jctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(decision.getClass());
    final Marshaller marshaller = jctx.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.marshal(decision, baos);
    System.out.println(baos.toString());
```

The java class with AnyXmlType property(decisionMotivation) is declared as follows

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "DecisionType",
         propOrder = {"diaryNumber", "preparedBy", "preparedDate", "applicant", "draft", "recommendation", "applicationRejected", "applicationGranted", "decisionMotivation", "note", "promotionLecturer", "degrees", "caseType", "textTemplate", "templateVersion", "decisionBasisForeign", "attachments"},
         namespace = "##default",
         factoryClass = DEFAULT.class,
         factoryMethod = "")
@XmlRootElement(namespace = "##default",
                name = "decision")
public class Decision
    implements java.io.Serializable
```

The AnyXmlType class is declared as follows

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "AnyXmlType",
         propOrder = {"any"},
         namespace = "##default",
         factoryClass = DEFAULT.class,
         factoryMethod = "")
public class AnyXmlType
    implements java.io.Serializable
```

the class has one property (any) of the type org.w3c.dom.Element
with a getter and a setter

Please could you help out by telling me what I am missing here?
Thanks in advance
Sam

Comment: Just forgott to mention that the Element any has the following information: <body>
<h1>Decision</h1>
<p>Text - some more text</p>
</body>